# how to get the username of a public key file

Tags: regex, ssh, rsa, public-key, pem

With a regex (bash, perl, python or ruby), how do you extract the username from a RSA public key pem file.

Comment: There is nothing like a username of a RSA public key. It looks like you refer to the username part of comment in the SSH public key.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
  # given a public key, extra username
  def extract_public_key_username(key)
    username_with_at_sign = key.split(" ")[2]
    username_with_at_sign.split("@")[0]
  end
```

seems to work